# How to get a value that never appear into specific property from the Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array that contains a list of objects with two properties `source` and `target`. I want to find a value that never appears into `target`.

Currently, I came up with a very weird solution. According to the provided code, I am creating two separate arrays by iterating through an `a` array. `all` with all elements and `targets` with only target elements. Then I apply a filter on it and it returns the answer.

```
    const a = [
      { source: '2', target: '3' },
      { source: '1', target: '2' },
      { source: '3', target: '4' },
      { source: '4', target: '5' }
    ];

    const all = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    const targets = ['3', '2', '4', '5'];
    console.log(all.filter(e => !targets.includes(e))[0]);
```

Do we have some efficient solution, which not demands to create these two arrays and I know return element would be only one. So I don't want to get an array as an answer

Comment: `find()` returns you first object that is found in an array.

Comment: target values are always in series? and should be 1 to n? how `all` array is created?

Comment: target value would not always be in series. My concern to find value among all values that never came in the target.

Comment: but what is `all value`?

Comment: That I am creating as follow: 
    let allC = new Array();
    a.forEach(({ source, target }) => {
      allC.push(source);
      allC.push(target);
    });
    console.log(new Set(allC));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.find` to find the first matching element:

```js
const a = [
  { source: '2', target: '3' },
  { source: '1', target: '2' },
  { source: '3', target: '4' },
  { source: '4', target: '5' }
];
const sources = [];
const targets = [];
a.forEach(({ source, target }) => {
  sources.push(source);
  targets.push(target);
});

console.log(sources.find(e => !targets.includes(e)));
```

If you want better performance, use a Set instead of an array for the `targets`, so you can use `.has` instead of `.includes` (resulting in overall complexity of `O(n)` rather than `O(n^2)`):

```js
const a = [
  { source: '2', target: '3' },
  { source: '1', target: '2' },
  { source: '3', target: '4' },
  { source: '4', target: '5' }
];
const sources = [];
const targets = new Set();
a.forEach(({ source, target }) => {
  sources.push(source);
  targets.add(target);
});

console.log(sources.find(e => !targets.has(e)));
```

Comment: Is there any way to not create this targets array and use existing `a` array

Comment: Just iterate through the `a` and add to each collection beforehand